# ServerSocket only receive one time

Tags: delphi, record, serversocket

I'm trying send a record over clientsocket and receive on serversocket, everything works well but only on first time, after send one time i need disconnect clientsocket, connect again to send it again.

If somebody can help me.

here is the server side code how i receive the informations:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  LMessageBuffer: TBytes;
  LDataSize: Integer;
  LProtocol: TProtocol;
begin
  LDataSize := Socket.ReceiveLength;

if LDataSize >= szProtocol then begin
    try
      Socket.ReceiveBuf(LBuffer, SizeOf(LBuffer));
      LProtocol := BytesToProtocol(LBuffer);

  // check client command and act accordingly
  case LProtocol.Command of
    cmdConnect: begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s]', ['Connect', LProtocol.Sender.UserName, TimeToStr(LProtocol.Sender.ID)]));
    end; // cmdConnect: begin
    cmdDisconnect: begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s]', ['Disconnect', LProtocol.Sender.UserName, TimeToStr(LProtocol.Sender.ID)]));
    end; // cmdDisconnect: begin
  end;
finally
  ClearBuffer(LBuffer);
end;
  end;
end;
```

and here the client side:

```
var
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  LProtocol: TProtocol;
  x : Integer;
begin
  InitProtocol(LProtocol);
  LProtocol.Command := cmdConnect;
  ClientData.UserName := Edit1.Text;
  ClientData.ID := Now;
  LProtocol.Sender := ClientData;
  LBuffer := ProtocolToBytes(LProtocol);
  try
    ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(LBuffer, Length(LBuffer));
  finally
    ClearBuffer(LBuffer);
  end;
```

record declaration:

```
type
  TCommand = (
    cmdConnect,
    cmdDisconnect,
    cmdMessageBroadcast,
    cmdMessagePrivate,
    cmdScreenShotGet,
    cmdScreenShotData);

// client information structure, you can extend this based on your needs
type
  TClient = record
    UserName: string[50];
    ID: TDateTime;
  end; // TClient = record

// size of the client information structure
const
  szClient = SizeOf(TClient);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You did not show what `TProtocol` is, how `szProtocol` is defined, or how a `TProtocol` is serialized to/from a byte array. Is the byte array always the same length, or is it variable in length? That makes a BIG difference in how you send it over the socket.

Answer (score 4):

`TBytes` is a dynamic array, but you are treating it as if it were a static array.

In your client code, you are not sending `LBuffer` correctly.  Being a dynamic array, `LBuffer` is just a pointer to data that is stored elsewhere in memory.  So, you need to dereference `LBuffer` to pass the correct memory address to `SendBuf()`.

In your server code, you are not even allocating any memory for `LBuffer` at all before reading bytes into it.  And, like in the client, you need to dereference `LBuffer` when passing it to `ReceiveBuf()`.  You also need to use the correct byte size when telling `ReceiveBuf()` how many bytes to read (`SizeOf(TBytes)` is the wrong value to use).

Lastly, you need to pay attention to the return values of `SendBuf()` and `ReceiveBuf()`, as they *CAN* return that fewer bytes than requested were processed!  So, you should be calling `SendBuf()` and `ReceiveBuf()` in a loop.

Try this:

```
var
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  LProtocol: TProtocol;
  LBufferPtr: PByte;
  LBufferLen: Integer;
  LNumSent: Integer;
begin
  InitProtocol(LProtocol);
  LProtocol.Command := cmdConnect;
  ClientData.UserName := Edit1.Text;
  ClientData.ID := Now;
  LProtocol.Sender := ClientData;
  LBuffer := ProtocolToBytes(LProtocol);
  LBufferPtr := PByte(LBuffer);
  LBufferLen := Length(LBuffer);
  repeat
    LNumSent := ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(LBufferPtr^, LBufferLen);
    if LNumSent = -1 then
    begin
      // if ClientSocket1.ClientType is set to ctNonBlocking,
      // uncomment this check ...
      {
      if WSAGetLastError() = WSAEWOULDBLOCK then
      begin
        // optionally call the Winsock select() function to wait
        // until the socket can accept more data before calling
        // SendBuf() again...
        Continue;
      end;
      }
      // ERROR!
      ClientSocket1.Close;
      Break;
    end; 
    Inc(LBufferPtr, LNumSent);
    Dec(LBufferLen, LNumSent);
  until LBufferLen = 0;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  LDataSize: Integer;
  LProtocol: TProtocol;
  LBufferPtr: PByte;
  LBufferLen: Integer;
  LNumRecvd: Integer;
begin
  LDataSize := Socket.ReceiveLength;
  if LDataSize < szProtocol then Exit;

  SetLength(LBuffer, szProtocol);

  repeat
    // since you are validating ReceiveLength beforehand, ReceiveBuf()
    // *should not* return fewer bytes than requested, but it doesn't
    // hurt to be careful...
    LBufferPtr := PByte(LBuffer);
    LBufferLen := szProtocol;
    repeat
      LNumRecvd := Socket.ReceiveBuf(LBufferPtr^, LBufferLen);
      if LNumRecvd <= 0 then Exit;
      Inc(LBufferPtr, LNumRecvd);
      Dec(LBufferLen, LNumRecvd);
      Dec(LDataSize, LNumRecvd);
    until LBufferLen = 0;

    LProtocol := BytesToProtocol(LBuffer);

    // check client command and act accordingly
    case LProtocol.Command of
      cmdConnect: begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s]', ['Connect', LProtocol.Sender.UserName, TimeToStr(LProtocol.Sender.ID)]));
      end;
      cmdDisconnect: begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s]', ['Disconnect', LProtocol.Sender.UserName, TimeToStr(LProtocol.Sender.ID)]));
      end;
    end;
  until LDataSize < szProtocol;
end;
```

---

That being said, `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` have been deprecated for a LONG time.  They are not even installed by default anymore (but are still available if you need to install them).  You should really consider switching to another socket library that handles these kind of details for you, such as Indy's `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` (Indy is preinstalled in Delphi), eg:

```
type
  PTIdBytes = ^TIdBytes;
var
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  LProtocol: TProtocol;
begin
  InitProtocol(LProtocol);
  LProtocol.Command := cmdConnect;
  ClientData.UserName := Edit1.Text;
  ClientData.ID := Now;
  LProtocol.Sender := ClientData;
  LBuffer := ProtocolToBytes(LProtocol);
  // TBytes and TIdBytes are technically the same thing under the hood,
  // but they are still distinct types and not assignment-compatible,
  // so using a dirty hack to pass a TBytes as a TIdBytes without having
  // to make a copy of the bytes...
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(PTIdBytes(@LBuffer)^);
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
type
  PTBytes = ^TBytes;
var
  LBuffer: TIdBytes;
  LProtocol: TProtocol;

  // note: TIdTCPServer is a multi-threaded component, so you must
  // sync with the main thread when accessing the UI...
  procedure AddToMemo(const AStr: string);
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(AStr);
      end
    );
  end;

begin
  // ReadBytes() can allocate the buffer for you...
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(LBuffer, szProtocol);

  // using a similar dirty hack to pass a TIdBytes as a TBytes
  // without making a copy of the bytes ...
  LProtocol := BytesToProtocol(PTBytes(@LBuffer)^);

  // check client command and act accordingly
  case LProtocol.Command of
    cmdConnect: begin
      AddToMemo(Format('[%s][%s][%s]', ['Connect', LProtocol.Sender.UserName, TimeToStr(LProtocol.Sender.ID)]));
    end;
    cmdDisconnect: begin
      AddToMemo(Format('[%s][%s][%s]', ['Disconnect', LProtocol.Sender.UserName, TimeToStr(LProtocol.Sender.ID)]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: On paste i have problems with TIdTCPServer with stuck connections, for this reason i don't used it more. you have some example to manage connections with him? i mean a record to save connected clients and manage their later.

on indy example don't need check if ReadBytes are < than protocol to avoid ppl connect and send strange informations?

Comment: @PâMBolsoni If you are having trouble managing clients in `TIdTCPServer`, please post a new question about that issue, and show your code. But note that `TIdTCPServer` tracks connected clients for you (in the `TIdTCPServer.Contexts` property), you don't need to keep track of them manually. As for `ReadBytes()`, it blocks until `szProtocol` number of bytes are received, similar to your `Socket.ReceiveLength` check in your `TServerSocket` code. It is your responsibility to validate the bytes received are what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, i just asked for TIdTCPServer, on SocketServer i check if length are < than protocol and i implemented a heart beat to determine is the connection its true or not.
later i try use TIdTCPServer again, not now.
i already solved the question after post this topic, but i'll analise your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Remy Lebeau using your example how i can send a text protocol to client?